# Running min 1 instance of Google-App-Engine in standard environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Looking at the Google-App-Engine's two environments, standard and flex, most of the features offered by standard seem more appropriate for my use case.

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments, both standard and flex environment support automatic scaling while standard can scale to 0 instances and flex can scale to 1 instance.

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref, an option for automatic scaling is specifying the min/max number of instances running at any given moment. I would have thought that this would 'override' standard environment's ability to scale to zero, but after my service had seen no traffic in 15 hours, it still closed the last remaining instance.

I have the following config-settings in my app.yaml file.

```
runtime: nodejs10
automatic_scaling:
   min_instances: 1
   max_instances: 1 # Increase in production
   target_cpu_utilization: 0.95
```

I was trying to force GAE to have 1 running instance at any time while in testing. I realize that having a static number of instances running is not the point of automatic scaling, but I plan to increase the maximum number of instances when moving to production. I have also tried adding min_idle_instances: 1 to the settings without any difference.

Can standard environment be forced to have a minimum of 1 running instance at any time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to ensure that your instance is ready to serve is to configure **[warm up request](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuring-warmup-requests)**.

Bear in mind that even with Warm up request, you might encounter loading request. If your app has no traffic, the first request will always be a loading request and not a warm up. Thus, in my opinion the best way to approach a situation like this is to set 2 min_instances.

- Example of an express.js handler:

  ```
  js
  const express = require('express');
  const app = express();

  app.get('/_ah/warmup', (req, res) => {
  // Handle your warmup logic. Initiate db connection, etc.
  });

  // Rest of your application handlers.
  app.get('/', handler);
  app.listen(8080);
  ```
- Example of app.yaml addition:

  ```
    inbound_services:
    - warmup
  ```

A workaround it could be to use **[cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml)** that triggers every minute, so your instance it will be available to serve you. However, even with this approach 2 min_instance is a better solution.

Comment: Warmup requests don't ensure an instance is available, they only make a best-effort attempt to not send a user request to an instance until it's up and running (which works only if some other instance is already running, for the 1st instance it'll always be a loading request, not a warmup one). Explained in the very doc you referenced.

Comment: You are right @Dan Cornilescu. Just edit my solution and added a workaround. Feel free to express your opinion on this matter.

Comment: How does having min 2 instances instead of 1 ensure not cold boots for users? One would think 1 would ensure no cold boots, - why 2?

Comment: You can experiment and find the best approach for you, although by the time I have answered the question, 2 min instances were the bear minimum to ensure that the warmup requests will be there and try to prepare your instance for the traffic it will receive.